# How remove all tibble dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I would like transform this line code :

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) == "data.frame"])
```

to apply for all data.frame and tbl_df

thanks in advance.

Comment: what about `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) %in% c("data.frame", "tbl_df")])`?

Comment: dont work with tibble :(

Comment: It'd be nice to have a reproducible example here.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of ugly, but I think this works.

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class), function(x) "data.frame" %in% x)])
```

When you do `class(my_tibble)` it gives you `c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")`. So the output you get from the first `sapply()` above gives you a list of vectors, which you can `sapply()` over a second time.

Although it may be easier to just restart your `R` session.